# Specifying Return Value using EnumDropDownListFor ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Instead of my HTML control returning the description in my enum class to the controller, can I instead use it to return the integer value?

```
public enum NoticeCategories : byte
{

[Display(Name= "High")]
High = 1,

[Display(Name = "Medium")]
Medium = 2,

[Display(Name = "Low")]
Low = 3
}
```

EDIT: Code in view

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.NoticeCategory, new {@class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Can you give a code example of how you are using this?

Comment: Show us your model. I bet the noticeCategory is of `string` type in there, otherwise ASP.NET Model Binder would've set the enum value properly. See this article for a concrete example and downloadable source code on how to work with Enums and `EnumDropDownListFor` function - http://nimblegecko.com/aspnetmvc-dropdowns-with-enums/

Answer (score 0):

Yes sure this way you can return integer value 
from `Enum`.

Exm :

```
roleModel.Priority = NoticeCategories.High;
```

Here `roleModel.Priority` is integer model property and I am assigning an `Enum` value to it by the `NoticeCategories.High` statement.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know what notice category the customer is going to choose. Is there a more dynamic way?